# Objective video quality assessment

Tags: video, video-editor, encoding, video-quality, decoding

I'm trying to develop a tool that given a video (without a reference video), it can measure the quality. Basically given some thresholds, it assigns them a rating (I just need 4 classes 1-4). Since we don't have the original reference videos, I'm **not** looking for approaches using SSIM or PSNR or such. Possible options are using machine learning approaches.

Is there any available tool or package for that? If not, how can I implement one?

Comment: If I understand your question correctly this https://github.com/Netflix/vmaf could help

Comment: @Marware But that one is still reference-based. Isn't it?

Comment: `reference_path and distorted_path are the paths to the reference and distorted video files` in `./run_vmaf format width height reference_path distorted_path [--out-fmt output_format]`

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for is called “no-reference quality assessment”. Google can give you specific examples.

Comment: Couldn't find an available tool for that, except some research papers.

Comment: Which answers your question as reading those research papers will allow you to implement your own tool. @TinaJ **¯\\_(ツ)_/¯ +1**

Comment: Haha I'm no more a phd student to spend time on that! Would prefer a ready-to-use tools.